# IndexError: Index out of bounds(Creating a new column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression, index-error

I am working on a dataset of football matches, i am using a linear Regression model to predict the final outcome, using the predicted values, i am trying to cross reference the predicted values for other matches and the final outcome to see if there is any pattern in the data, which returns the most consistent outcome, i am trying to map it to a column in the dataset so i could go through everything at the same time but I keep getting an ***IndexError***

```
x0 = epl_data_main2[['FTHG', 'FTAG']]
x1 = epl_data_main2[['Home_standev','Home_var']]
x2 = epl_data_main2[['Away_standev','Away_var']]
y = epl_data_main2[['FTHG']]
y1 = epl_data_main2[['FTAG']]
y2 = epl_data_main2['FTR_Home']
y3 = epl_data_main2['FTR_Draw']
y4 = epl_data_main2['FTR_Away']
reg = LinearRegression()
reg1 = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x1, y)
reg1.fit(x2, y1)
reg2 = LinearRegression()
reg3 = LinearRegression()
reg4 = LinearRegression()
reg2.fit(x0, y2)
reg3.fit(x0, y3)
reg4.fit(x0, y4)
PTeam1_Score = epl_data_main2.apply(lambda row:reg.predict([[row['Home_standev'],row['Home_var']]]), axis=1)

PTeam2_Score = epl_data_main2.apply(lambda row:reg1.predict([[row['Away_standev'],row['Away_var']]]), axis=1)

epl_data_main2["PTeam1_Score"] = PTeam1_Score
epl_data_main2["PTeam1_Score"] = epl_data_main2["PTeam1_Score"].map(lambda x: float(x))
epl_data_main2["PTeam2_Score"] = PTeam2_Score
epl_data_main2["PTeam2_Score"] = epl_data_main2["PTeam2_Score"].map(lambda x: float(x))

POutcome_Home = epl_data_main2.apply(lambda row:reg2.predict([[row["PTeam1_Score"],row["PTeam2_Score"]]]), axis=1)
epl_data_main2["POutcome_Home"] = POutcome_Home

POutcome_Draw = epl_data_main2.apply(lambda row:reg3.predict([[row["PTeam1_Score"],row["PTeam2_Score"]]]), axis=1)
epl_data_main2["POutcome_Draw"] = POutcome_Draw

POutcome_Away= epl_data_main2.apply(lambda row:reg4.predict([[row["PTeam1_Score"],row["PTeam2_Score"]]]), axis=1)
epl_data_main2["POutcome_Away"] = POutcome_Away

epl_data_main2["POutcome_Away"] = epl_data_main2["POutcome_Away"].map(lambda x: float(x))
epl_data_main2["POutcome_Home"] = epl_data_main2["POutcome_Home"].map(lambda x: float(x))
epl_data_main2["POutcome_Draw"] = epl_data_main2["POutcome_Draw"].map(lambda x: float(x))
epl_data_main3 = epl_data_main2[["FTHG","FTAG","PTeam1_Score","PTeam2_Score","POutcome_Home","POutcome_Draw","POutcome_Away"]].copy(deep=True)
Outcome = epl_data.apply(lambda row:custom_result(row['FTR']),axis=1)
Over = epl_data_main3.apply(lambda row:goals(row["FTHG"],row["FTAG"]), axis=1)
btts = epl_data_main3.apply(lambda row:
                           1
                           if ((int(row['FTHG'] != 0) and int(row['FTAG']) != 0))
                           else 0, axis=1)
epl_data_main3["Outcome"] = Outcome
epl_data_main3["Over"] = Over
epl_data_main3["btts"] = btts
def pred(home,away,score1,score2,data):
    a,b,c = 0,0,0
    val = [home,away,score1,score2]
    for i in range(len(val)):
        if i == 0:
            curr = data[(data.POutcome_Home >= trunc(val[0], 3)) & (data.POutcome_Home < trunc((val[0]+0.001),3)) &
                        (data.POutcome_Away >= trunc(val[1], 2)) & (data.POutcome_Away < trunc((val[1]+0.01),2)) &
                        (data.PTeam1_Score >= trunc(val[2], 2)) & (data.PTeam1_Score < trunc((val[2]+0.01),2)) &
                        (data.PTeam2_Score >= trunc(val[3], 2)) & (data.PTeam2_Score < trunc((val[3]+0.01),2))]
            a = curr.groupby('Outcome').Outcome.count()
            b = curr.groupby('Over').Over.count()
            c = curr.groupby('btts').btts.count()
elif i == 3:
            curr = data[(data.POutcome_Home >= trunc(val[0], 2)) & (data.POutcome_Home < trunc((val[0]+0.01),2)) &
                        (data.POutcome_Away >= trunc(val[1], 2)) & (data.POutcome_Away < trunc((val[1]+0.01),2)) &
                        (data.PTeam1_Score >= trunc(val[2], 2)) & (data.PTeam1_Score < trunc((val[2]+0.01),2)) &
                        (data.PTeam2_Score >= trunc(val[3], 3)) & (data.PTeam2_Score < trunc((val[3]+0.001),3))]
            try:
                a[0] += curr.groupby('Outcome').Outcome.count()[0]
                a[1] += curr.groupby('Outcome').Outcome.count()[1]
                a[2] += curr.groupby('Outcome').Outcome.count()[2]
                b[0] += curr.groupby('Over').Over.count()[0]
                b[1] += curr.groupby('Over').Over.count()[1]
                c[0] += curr.groupby('btts').btts.count()[0]
                c[1] += curr.groupby('btts').btts.count()[1]
            except KeyError:
                a[0] += 0
                a[1] += 0
                a[2] += 0
                b[0] += 0
                b[1] += 0
                c[0] += 0
                c[1] += 0
    predict = []
    if a[0] > (a[1] and a[2]):
        predict.append("Draw")
    elif a[1] > (a[0] and a[2]):
        predict.append("Home")
    elif a[2] > (a[0] and a[1]):
        predict.append("Away")
    if b[0] > b[1]:
        predict.append("Under2.5")
    else:
        predict.append("Over2.5")
    if c[0] > c[1]:
        predict.append("No-BTTS")
    else:
        predict.append("BTTS")
    return predict
```

I try this but it keeps giving error

```
       pred_val = epl_data_main3.apply(lambda row:
                     pred(
                         row['POutcome_Home'],
                         row['POutcome_Away'],
                         row['PTeam1_Score'],
                         row['PTeam2_Score'],
                         epl_data_main3),axis=1)
```

pred_val
This is what print out

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4409 
   4410             try:
-> 4411                 return libindex.get_value_at(s, key)
   4412             except IndexError:
   4413                 raise

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at()

pandas\_libs\util.pxd in pandas._libs.util.get_value_at()

pandas\_libs\util.pxd in pandas._libs.util.validate_indexer()

IndexError: index out of bounds
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide your data set and more of your code. YOu want to provide enough details so that the error can be reproducible for us to debug

Comment: @chitown88 i have done that now

Comment: you  still need to supply your dataset `epl_data_main2` or at least a sample of it.